# Expanding vectors inside a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using a matrix of characters by defining a vector of vectors of chars the following way.

```
std::vector<std::vector <char> > CharMap;
std::vector <char> temp(sizeY, '.');
std::vector <std::vector <char> > temp2(sizeX, temp);
CharMap = temp2;
```

This has been working fine so far, but now I need to expand the innermost vectors during runtime and something is going wrong.

```
cout << (int) CharMap[0].size();
CharMap[0].push_back( '.' );
cout << (int) CharMap[0].size();
```

`CharMap[0]` is a vector of `char`s. This code compiles with no problem. When it runs, the size of the vector simply doesn't change. All I'm trying to do here is increase the size by 1, but the ouput is the same on both `cout`s. Why isn't the size increasing?

*Inside the actual code I will increase the size of all `CharMap[i]`, iterating over`i`. But right now even this simplified version isn't working.*

Comment: Post real code. The error is likely elsewhere. Also don't just add casts to `int` for no reason. Use `valgrind` to check for out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: `temp2` is unnecessary. Create `CharMap` after `temp` with the correct args.

Comment: Run your program through valgrind and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Neither of the temps are necessary: `std::vector<std::vector<char> > CharMap(sizeX, std::vector<char>(sizeX, '.'))` should suffice.

Comment: @JamesKanze The temps are there for readability, because temp2 is used to construct 4 other similar maps. This is not a time sensitive operation and they're both properly destroyed once the function ends.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Unfortunately, SDL generates so many error messages in valgrind that it's impossible to debug at all with it. =/ I'll probably get rid o SDL before trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @BruceConnor A temp named temp does not help readability any.  Using extra variables can help readability when they have semantically significant names, of course, but using a single definition seems more idiomatic for C++ in this case.  (There's also a distinct advantage in terms of memory usage.  The initializer expressions are destructed at the at the end of the definition statement; named temporaries are only destructed at the end of the block.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test program seems to work as expected:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<char> temp(17, '.');
    std::vector<std::vector<char> > map(10, temp);

    for (int i=0; i<map.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Before addition, size = " << map[i].size();
        map[i].push_back('.');
        std::cout << ", after addition, size = " << map[i].size() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I suppose you could try that and see what it produces with your compiler -- it's barely possible it won't, in which case you've apparently discovered a bug. If it does work, then the problem is apparently in some code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. finding this bug in the rest of the code will demand quite a bit off work. I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid before delving into it.